# skip importing rows based on value

Tags: php

I am importing csv file into mysql DB. Csv file contains 4 columns, if the 4th column contains value "RTS - Return To Shipper" , than i want to skip that row when importing.....

```
 if(isset($_POST["Import"])){

             $filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];     
             if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0)
             {
                $file = fopen($filename, "r");
                $i=0;
                while (($getData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
                 {              
                    if($i==0){$i++;continue;}

                    $sql = "INSERT into do_order (tracking_id,
                    order_id,
                    payment_type                                    
                    )

                       values ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn , $getData[0])."',
                       '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn , $getData[1])."',
                       '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn , $getData[2])."'                                         
                       ) 
                       ";

                       $result=$db_handle->executeUpdate($sql);
                 }
             }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try the obvious solution: `if ($getData[3]=="RTS") continue;`? If yes, what happened?

Comment: @KarstenKoop thanks, please post your comment as answer.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just skip the line if you encounter the string you are looking for in the 4th column:

```
 while (($getData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
 {
   if ($getData[3] == "RTS - Return To Shipper")
      continue;
   [...]
```